# The probability that an order statistic is a particular sample member?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, order-statistics

Suppose I have $X_i, \ldots, X_n$ sample members that are all iid and follow some variable $Y$.

If I seek to find the probability that $Y_k = X_m$ (the $k$th order statistic where $1 \leq m \leq n$), my textbook claims that since all members are iid, the chance that any one of them equals some statistic $=\frac 1 n$.

I'm not convinced by this explanation. What about the independence of these sample members implies that they're equally to be assumed by some order statistic?

Comment: Of course, i.i.d. implies their probabilities to be some order statistic are the same, due to symmetry. But the statement that the probability is $1/n$ is not correct in general, since those probabilities do not necessarily add to $1$. This happens usually when the probability distribution is not continuous. The simplest example may be that, all $X_i$'s take value $0$ with probability $1$, then the probability that $Y_k=X_m$ is also $1$.

Comment: Perhaps think of it like this...  we're going to sample the $X_i,$ but before I do, I ask you to bet on which one will be the third largest.  You have no way of telling them apart, so a priori they all have the same chance of being third largest.  Since one of them WILL in fact be third largest, the probabilities are all $1/n$.  Perhaps you might want to review what "order statistic" means?  (Those probabilities you mention do in fact add up to 1.)

Comment: You wrote "What about the independence of these sample members[?]".  Independence is part of what "i.i.d." means.  But independence alone is not enough: Suppose $X_1$ is equal to $0$ or $1$ each with probability $1/2$ and $X_2$ is equal to $3$ or $4$ each with probability $1/2$, and $X_1,X_2$ are independent. Then obviously the events $X_1 = X_{(1)}$ and that $X_2=X_{(1)}$ are not equally probable.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I see why both are necessary. Thanks! Another way to express my puzzlement is to ask the question: "Suppose an order statistic were more likely to take any one sample member: why would that imply that the sample members aren't independent (assuming they are uniformly distributed)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are i.i.d. and $X_1$ has a certain distribution is enough information to determine the joint distribution completely. In other words, if each of the random variables $W_1,W_2,W_3,W_4$ has the same distribution as $X_1$ and $W_1,W_2,W_3,W_4$ are independent then the whole sequence $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ has the same distribution as $(W_1,W_2,W_3,W_4)$. That means, in particular, that permutations of $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ have that same distribution, so that, for example, $(X_2,X_3,X_4,X_1)$ has the same distribution as $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$. Therefore, the probability that, for example, the third component of $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is in the second position after sorting into increasing order, is the same as the probability that the third component of $(X_2,X_3,X_4,X_1)$ is in the second position when sorted into increasing order. Thus $\Pr(X_3=X_{(2)}) = \Pr(X_4=X_{(2)}).$ And the same holds if some other pair than $3,4$ had been chosen as the indices and some other position than the second had been chosen. Consequently, every index among $1,2,3,4$ is equally likely to be the index of the random variable in the second position after sorting.  And similarly for other positions than the second.